# Handling categorical data in estimateNetwork for network analysis

Tags: r, network-analysis

I'm very new to R, and I apologise for this being such a rudimentary question.

I have data organised in an Excel sheet with Subjects coded as "Subject001", "Subject 020" etc, and their sex coded as M/F. There is already a separate column for which dummy numbers have been assigned to their sex, 1 to M and 2 to F.

I am trying to to network analysis with the code

```
network <- estimateNetwork(mydf, default = "EBICglasso", corMethod = "spearman")
```

but got the error message that `x` must be numeric.

So I tried to change the string values to integers using

```
cols.num <- c("SubjectID", "Sex")
mydf_healthy[cols.num] <- sapply(mydf_healthy[cols.num], as.numeric)
ssapply(mydf_healthy, class)
```

but when I try to run the network analysis code, I get the message

> qgraph::EBICglasso for EBIC model selection
> - using glasso::glasso
> Error in eigen(corMat) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
> In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

I see that my string data in the Subject and Sex columns have become NA.

Would someone be able to help me out please?

**Edited**: Here are the first five rows and columns of the mydf_healthy output

X SubjectID Sex Age TestScore1

1 Sub_001    m   28     11

2 Sub_015    m   55     13

3 Sub_023    f   75     30

4 Sub_045    m   37     29

5 Sub_046    f   40     29

All columns following the TestScore1 column consist only of numerical values for different test scores. Only SubjectID and Sex are non-numerical. X does not really mean anything, this is automated numbering. I need to keep the subject IDs to know which subject the eventual network analysis is referring to.

The nature of the numerical values is also different: age represents just the factual age of the participant, however in all following columns these are test scores. Do these need to be treated differently?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Please include any non-base libraries you're using. The question should probably be "how to use `estimateNetwork` on categorical data"

Comment: Hi! Could you share the first few lines of `mydf_healthy` by editing your question to include the output of `dput(head(mydf_healthy, 5))`? At first thought, you could try `sapply(mydf_healthy[cols.num], as.factor)`

Comment: I installed library(bootnet), (qgraph), (networktools) and (NetworkComparisonTest). I have edited the question too to include the output of mydf_healthy. 

I tried the "sapply... as.factor" line of code suggested, however I get the error message, "Estimating Network. Using package::function:
  - qgraph::EBICglasso for EBIC model selection
    - using glasso::glasso
Error in cor(x = list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,  : 
  'x' must be numeric"

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that all columns are numeric. Please also note that all columns should encode Gaussian variables (or at least somewhat similar to Gaussian variables), so a binary variable as gender does not work well with the `EBICglasso`. For this you can better use a mixed graphical model (`mgm`). You cannot include the subject ID variable in the network; it is meaningless and does not encode a Gaussian variable that interacts with other variables.